# windbg and VS can't find my pdb file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a project I have built using SCons and the MS VS 2013 (express) compiler (compiled from the command line).

It compiles and runs, however, it is crashing periodically, and so I want to debug it.

I added the following flags:

```
/Zi    # Debug symbols
/DEBUG # Debug symbols
/FS    # Concurrent debug database file access
```

After building, I see a `pdb` file generated called `vc120.pdb`.  My executable is located in a `build` folder, and the `pdb` file is in the main project directory.

However, when I try to attach my executable for debugging via VS2013 or WinDbg, I always get an error that the debug symbols could not be found.

I added the 'path' to the `pdb` file in both VS2013 and WinDbg, but I get the same result.  I also tried copying the `pdb` file into the `build` directory (to make it beside my executable), but no dice.  I even changed the name of the `pdb` file to match the name of my executable, but that didn't work either.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: vc120.pdb doesn't look like your program pdb file. It should be program_name.pdb.

Comment: I think you should describe you project settings in more detail. Also: There is a Linker option that specifies the name and path of the output PDB file - check that.

Comment: @AlexFarber - the default PDB file generated in Visual Studio is generally `vc<tools version>.pdb`. I always rename it to `$(ProjectName).pdb` as it reduces the likelihood of errors like this.

Comment: To get more info about what's going wrong you could try the `!sym noisy` option in windbg as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002285/windbg-display-symbol-server-paths-of-loaded-modules-even-if-the-symbols-did-n

Comment: @the_mandrill: Visual Studio generates both `$(ProjectName).pdb` and `vc<tools version>.pdb`. If `$(ProjectName).pdb` is not generated, something is wrong in the project settings.

Comment: I've had a number of problems in the past that arose because *only* the `vc100.pdb` file was generated -- I guess it may depend on the history of your project (eg updated through VS2008, VS2010...)

Comment: Ahhh...thanks for all the comments guys.  I think the issue is a misconfigured SConstruct file - I added `/DEBUG` as a compiler flag, when I think it needs to be a linker flag...I'll try it out tonight.

Comment: That was it!  Just added `/DEBUG` as a compiler flag and it worked!  Thanks all!  If someone wants to post the solution below, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, I discovered the issue was a misconfigured SCons file.

I added `/DEBUG` as a linker flag, instead of a compiler flag, and it worked.