# How does symstore calculate the directory hash value

Tags: hash, symbols, pdb-files, symstore

I am looking for the hash algorithm that symstore uses to create the directory name.  I found this link [Microsoft Symbol Server / Local Cache Hash Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419347/microsoft-symbol-server-local-cache-hash-algorithm) that describes the data elements that are used to generate the hash, but it does not go into any detail on how the hash value is calculated.  I am interested to see how symstore generates the hash directory and if anyone has any sample code that they can show, that would be great!

Comment: Actually the 1419347 describes the fields, but not how the calculation is performed.  This is why this question was posted

Answer (score 10):

symstore.exe calculates hash directory names as follows:

For PDB files, the GUID + Age, are used. Here is a python example:

```
pdb = pdbparse.parse("some.pdb")
pdb.STREAM_PDB.load()
guid = pdb.STREAM_PDB.GUID
guid_str = "%.8X%.4X%.4X%s" % (guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,
                               guid.Data4.encode("hex").upper())

symstore_hash = "%s%s" % (guid_str, pdb.STREAM_PDB.Age)
```

For PE (exe/dll) files, the TimeDateStamp (from IMAGE_FILE_HEADER) and SizeOfImage (from IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER) are used. Here is a python example:

```
pe = pefile.PE("some.exe")

symstore_hash = "%X%X" % (pe.FILE_HEADER.TimeDateStamp,
                          pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage)
```

Here is an example python script that prints symstore hash values for PDB and PE files:

https://gist.github.com/lennartblanco/9a70961a5aa66fe49df6

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you have already reviewed [this](http://www.google.com/patents?id=2GV4AAAAEBAJ&zoom=4&dq=microsoft%20symbol%20store&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=directory&f=false) but it is the U.S. Patent describing the symbol store process.  Its pretty dense as you can imagine but it does describe in quite a bit of detail how the symbol store directories are expanded and deleted (specifically in sections 6, 7, 8).  Hope this helps or points you in the right direction.